# Linux schedule task when another is done

Tags: linux, process, cron, task, schedule

I have a task/process currently running.  I would like to schedule another task to start when the first one finished.

How can I do that in linux ?

(I can't stop the first one, and create a script to start one task after the other)

Comment: Are the tasks related? (I bet they are) Can they be made to cooperate? Do they originate from the same userid ? Are it cron jobs , or started from an interactive session?

Comment: not related, no cooperation possible, from the same userid, first one started from an interactive session, second one ... as recommended

Comment: razvan, what does "as recommended" mean in this context?

Comment: as recommended by people answering

Comment: So ... if my answer matched your needs, can you make it accepted? :)

Comment: didn't try it yet ... I will as soon as I try it and it works

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat meager spec, but something along the line of

```
watch -n 1 'pgrep task1 || task2'
```

might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You want **wait**.

Either the system call in section 2 of the manual, one of it's varients like `waitpid` or the shell builtin which is designed explicitly for this purpose.

---

The shell builtin is a little more natural because both processes are childred of the sell, so you write a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
command1 arguments &
wait 
command2 args
```

---

To use the system calls you will have to write a program that forks, launches the first command in the child then `wait`s before execing the second program.

The manpage for `wait (2)` says:

> **wait() and waitpid()**
>         The wait() system call suspends execution of the current process until one of its children terminates.  The call wait(&status) is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>       waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
> ```
>
> The  waitpid()  system  call suspends execution of the current process until a child 
>   specified by pid argument has changed state.

Comment: why fork & wait if you can do `command1 arguments;
command2 args` ?

Comment: Different contexts. One is compiled program (say c or c++) while the other is in a shell script. In any case, what the shell does when running  `command1` *is* `fork` and `exec`, and then the `wait` builtin calls the `wait` system call, so it amounts to the same thing.